# Google Apps Script getText + replaceText from text box inside drawing in Google Docs Impossible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, drawing, google-docs

I'm trying to edit an Avery template in google docs and populate it with information form a google sheet Via Google Apps Script.

I already body.replaceText to replace the placeholder text in the doc:

```
 for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
    var body = doc.getActiveSection();
    body.replaceText("%NAME%", row[0]);
    body.replaceText("%ADD_LN1%", row[1]);
    body.replaceText("%ADD_LN2%", row[2]);
```

The label template is a table with a drawing oval in each segment and I have inserted a text box inside the The problem i'm having that I have a text box inside the oval drawings in the doc (I need the oval drawings to know where the labels will print)

The placeholder text inside the drawing will not change when I run my script, but any test inside the table or on the page normally will change to the Google sheets information.

Here is the label template I am using: [Label Page](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18aUoTtf_z7KkTkUmwIDtn-9vUQbzU_HYLj3jD681z24/edit?usp=sharing)
I have placed the %NAME& tag in the header, on the image and on the image that is formatted to freeze in place on page (Just in case that changes anything!)

Purpose: I have a google sheet populated with customer name address and custom choices (specific safety information to print onto a label)
I then have this script insert the info into the label doc, then i can print it without having to create them from scratch every time manually.

If there isn't a way to get text / replace text that is within drawing-shape-text, is there a way I can use the circular shape as a table of as guidelines so that I can transfer across the data as standard?

If you need any more info please let me know, I'm very green and very confused.

Thank you in advance for anyone taking the time to read through this!

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are not methods for directly modifying the texts in the drawing in the methods of Google Apps Script. But, when the Google Document is converted to DOCX format, the texts in the drawings can be modified. But when the Google Document is converted to DOCX format, the color of the drawings is changed. It seems that this might be due to the specification of DOCX format or Google side. I apologize for this. Even when the color of drawings is changed, when you want to replace the text, there is a workaround using Google Apps Script.

Comment: So essentially you would like to replace all the text in the shapes with your own values? @Daedalus

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, is there no workaround?

Comment: @ale13 yes , the way that a presentation slide would "shape.getText().replaceAllText" but for a google doc not a google slide.. seems so foreign to me that there aren't similar commands in each google file type

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, I have no idea for other workaround except for my 1st comment. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, I will try google slides instead as that seem like the solution, how do i close a thread?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are not methods for directly modifying the texts in the drawing in the methods of Google Apps Script.
From user - [Tannaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)

Google slides has the function I was looking for.

Comment: Any updates to the solution in 2023?